# Font changing back for no apparent reason

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Writing up a rough grammar in XeLaTeX and using fontspec to change the default font to Bitstream Charter instead of CM. Everything works fine for the first page or so of output, but on the second page the font abruptly changes back to Computer Modern. I can't find any reason for it. My preamble is set up like so:

```
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\la{Brill Roman}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\renewcommand{\p}{\textipa}
```

The output on the second page looks like this:
[image: Output Visual]

And the actual LaTeX code for that region runs like so.

```
\item \la{V} $\to$ any of the vowels or diphthongs.
\item \la{C2} $\to$ optional; restricted to nasals, fricatives, and \la{/l/}.

\end{enumerate}

\item \la{N} -- syllabic nasal. May be any of the nasals.

\end{enumerate}

\large{\textbf{Stress}}

Stress is always on the penultimate syllable.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\large` is a switch, not a command with argument. Similar for your `\la` command.

Comment: If you want to be able to use Brill’s italics, bold, and bold italics, note that the name of the font family is Brill, not Brill Roman.

Answer (score 4):

An up-to-date TeX distribution has the XCharter OpenType font, so you can use it instead of `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch}` which will not give you anything except for ASCII characters.

Moreover `\la` as you defined it is just a switch that tells XeLaTeX to use Brill from that point on.

A correct document would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}
\newfontfamily\lafont{Brill Roman}[Color=FF0000]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\la}{\lafont}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\p}{\textipa}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \la{V} $\to$ any of the vowels or diphthongs.
\item \la{C2} $\to$ optional; restricted to nasals, fricatives, and \la{/l/}.
\item \la{N} -- syllabic nasal. May be any of the nasals.
\end{enumerate}

{\large\textbf{Stress}\par}

Stress is always on the penultimate syllable.

\end{document}
```

Note that `\la` now *does* take an argument, but `\large` doesn't. The text is in the Charter font, while text in the argument of `\la` will be in Brill (I colored them in red just for bigger emphasis in the example, remove the `Color=FF0000` option).

[image]

If you have not `XCharter` among your system fonts, you can use a more complex setup:

```
\setmainfont{XCharter}[%
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Roman,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]
```

Note also that `xunicode` and `xltxtra` should generally not be loaded.

Depending on the version of `fontspec` you have available, you might need to switch the order of the mandatory and optional arguments to `\setmainfont` and `\newfontfamily`:

```
\newfontfamily\lafont[Color=FF0000]{Brill Roman}
\setmainfont[%
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Roman,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]{XCharter}
```

In this case it's better if you update your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 3):

in

```
\la{N}
```

the `{}` are not doing anything, `\la` does not take an argument, it switches font for the remainder of the current group. In this case that is the `\end{enumerate}` So at that point the font (and any other local declarations) revert to the values they had at `\begin{enumerate}`.

It isn't clear if you intended `\la` just to change the font of `N` or if you 
wanted to change the font for the while document in which case you could use

```
 \setmainfont{Brill Roman}
```